# Chat history - image loads before text - android

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, retrofit, chat

I have a chat application and now I'm on history part.(I'm using this library - https://github.com/stfalcon-studio/ChatKit) I'm getting data from server, then I check if it's a text I display it, else if it's an image then I request with retrofit for getting the image bytes array(the image came from server is in text format, so I need an additional call for getting the imageBytes and show it with Glide.). My problem is that example in my chat there is a TEXT1, TEXT2, IMAGE1, IMAGE2, TEXT3, IMAGE3, TEXT4. The history loads like this` IMAGE1, IMAGE2, IMAGE3, TEXT1, TEXT2, TEXT3, TEXT4.

Here is my code.

```
public class ChatSample extends BaseFragment {

private View mainView;
private ApiClient apiClient;
private MessageList messageList;
private MessagesListAdapter<Message> messagesAdapter;
private String myUserName;
private String sender;
private Message message;
private MessagesHistory[] messagesHistory;

private static final String BUNDLE_USER_NAME = "personUserNameBundle";
private final String senderId = "0";
private static final String TAG = "4564323";
private final int CHAT_IMAGE_TYPE = 5;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_fragment, container, false);
    apiClient = ApiClient.getInstance();

    //Setting my userName and other users userName
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    sender = bundle.getString(BUNDLE_USER_NAME);
    myUserName = SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().getUserData().getUserName();


    //A function for image loading
    ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader() {
        @Override
        public void loadImage(ImageView imageView, String s, byte[] imageBytes) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Glide");
            if (imageBytes != null) {
                Glide.with(getActivity()).load(imageBytes).into(imageView);
            }
        }
    };

    messageList = (MessageList) mainView.findViewById(R.id.chatKitList);
    messagesAdapter = new MessagesListAdapter<>(senderId, imageLoader);
    messageList.setAdapter(messagesAdapter);


    //Getting date for requesting history
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);

    Calendar mCurrentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = mCurrentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = mCurrentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = mCurrentDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + 1;
    mCurrentDate.set(year, month, day);

    Calendar earlierDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    int earlierYear = earlierDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int earlierMonth = earlierDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int earlierDay = earlierDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) - 7;
    earlierDate.set(earlierYear, earlierMonth, earlierDay);

    String currentTextDate = dateFormat.format(mCurrentDate.getTime());
    String earlierTextDate = dateFormat.format(earlierDate.getTime());

    //requesting history
    getMessages(earlierTextDate, currentTextDate);

    return mainView;
}


//History request
public void getMessages(final String from, final String to) {
    Call<MessagesHistory[]> getMessageHistory = apiClient.getMessageHistory(from, to);
    getMessageHistory.enqueue(new Callback<MessagesHistory[]>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<MessagesHistory[]> call, Response<MessagesHistory[]> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                messagesHistory = response.body();

                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
                dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));

                //Getting all information about history
                for (int i = 0; i < messagesHistory.length; i++) {
                    String messageSender = messagesHistory[i].getSender();
                    String messageReceiver = messagesHistory[i].getReceiver();
                    final String messages = messagesHistory[i].getText();
                    String date = messagesHistory[i].getSendtime();

                    Date convertDate = new Date();
                    try {
                        convertDate = dateFormat.parse(date);
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    convertDate.getTime();

                    //If I'm sending message
                    if (messageSender.equals(myUserName) && messageReceiver.equals(sender)) {

                        //If that is an image message
                        if(messages.startsWith("gago+")) {
                            getImagesHistory(convertDate, messages, "0");
                        } else {

                            //If that is a text message
                            getMessagesHistory(convertDate, messages, "0", null);
                        }
                    }

                    //If other user sends me a message
                    if (messageReceiver.equals(myUserName) && messageSender.equals(sender)) {

                        //If that is an image message
                        if(messages.startsWith("gago+")) {
                            getImagesHistory(convertDate, messages, "1");
                        } else {

                            //If that is a text message
                            getMessagesHistory(convertDate, messages, "1", null);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<MessagesHistory[]> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "An error occurred", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

//Request an image when I already have the image name
public void getImagesHistory(final Date convertDate, final String messages, final String id) {
    String cutMessage = messages.substring(5, messages.length());
    Call<ResponseBody> getChatImageCall = apiClient.getImages(cutMessage, CHAT_IMAGE_TYPE);
    getChatImageCall.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, final Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                try {
                    getMessagesHistory(convertDate, messages, id, response.body().bytes());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "An error occurred", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

//Display the message we got
public void getMessagesHistory(final Date startDate, final String historyMessages, final String id, byte[] imgBytes) {
    ArrayList<Message> messages = new ArrayList<>();

    //I'm getting my images with an array of byte
    //So if the image bytes are not null
    if(imgBytes != null) {
        message = MessagesFixtures.getImageBytesMessage(imgBytes, id);
    } else {
        //This is a text
        message = MessagesFixtures.getTextMessage(historyMessages, id);
    }
    message.setCreatedAt(startDate);
    messages.add(message);
    messagesAdapter.addToEnd(messages, false);

}
}
```

In my code `messagesAdapter.addToEnd(messages, false);` brings the array of messages and sets to recyclerView. In my case `recyclerView` is the `MessageList` and the adapter is `MessagesListAdapter`. So i think I need to pull out the  `messagesAdapter.addToEnd(messages, false);` from `getMessagesHistory` function and add in another place. But I can't do that, because `getMessagesHistory` has some parameters in constructor and the last argument `byte[] imgBytes` in some case it's null. When I get text message from server, I set it null else I set there my bytes of array. So please help how can I do this part?

Comment: You're triggering async methods in other async methods. For async methods order of execution != order of responses. Probably images come first because of Glide cache.

Comment: So what can I do here?

Comment: `getMessages` should be only asynchronous method, and it should call other requests synchronously. Better solution should implement chaining on data level - some order field etc.

Comment: Ok but what you mean saying "implement chaining on data level - some order field etc."

Comment: Remote Image or Message object should contain order field. So you will know where to insert that.

Comment: In case of image you can see in top where he loads image with glide, it creates an imageview and adds there. I'm getting date too and with date it sorts automatically.

Comment: Hi Hayk, Do you have a working example code, you can share, I am also trying to get a chat app working with getting the chats from my api with retrofit2/rxjava2 ?

Comment: Hi. My code is not in RxJava2, but I can describe you what was my problem. First of all my chat works on SocketCluster library (https://socketcluster.io/#!/) and ChatKit library (https://github.com/stfalcon-studio/ChatKit). Sorry I can't share my code.